# Majority of TXs are dropped by RPC

Tags: rpc, validator, transaction

While hosting a non-voting validator (RPC node) I noticed that a majority of TXs sent to it are being dropped, the RPC node starts with the following args:

> --identity ~/validator-keypair.json 
> --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
> --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
> --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
> --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
> --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
> --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 
> --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ 
> --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ 
> --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S 
> --only-known-rpc 
> --no-voting 
> --no-snapshot-fetch 
> --private-rpc 
> --rpc-port 8899 
> --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 
> --vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json 
> --log ~/log/solana-validator.log 
> --accounts /mt/accounts/solana-accounts 
> --ledger /mt/ledger/validator-ledger 
> --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
> --limit-ledger-size 
> --full-rpc-api

These are the default args found [in the solana labs guide](https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/setup-a-validator). In the logs I see the following:

```
[2024-02-02T23:28:01.605266057Z INFO  solana_quic_client::nonblocking::quic_client] 
Made 0rtt connection to 202.8.8.52:8009 with id 139194177714192 try_count 0, 
last_connection_id: 139483630342160, last_error: 
Some(ConnectionError(ApplicationClosed(ApplicationClose { error_code: 1, reason: 
b"dropped" })))

[2024-02-02T23:28:01.655178394Z INFO  solana_quic_client::nonblocking::quic_client] 
Error sending to 208.91.106.87:8009 with id 139177516703760, error 
WriteError(ConnectionLost(ApplicationClosed(ApplicationClose { error_code: 1, reason: 
b"dropped" }))) thread: ThreadId(1763)

[2024-02-02T23:28:01.655198774Z WARN  solana_quic_client::nonblocking::quic_client] 
Failed to send data async to 208.91.106.87:8009, error: 
Custom("WriteError(ConnectionLost(ApplicationClosed(ApplicationClose { error_code: 1, 
reason: b\"dropped\" })))")
```

Followed by "Retrying transaction" and "Dropped transaction due to max retries" logs. This happens even when sending single transactions to the node.

Things I tried:

1. Using standard args from the official guide (as seen above)
2. Storing ledger/ accounts on different NVMe ssds
3. Increasing dynamic-port-range
4. Disabling firewall altogether
5. Using different server location
6. Using different, stronger hardware
7. Using/ not using account indexes
8. Played around with `tpu-disable-quic` and `tpu-enable-udp` flags

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, it doesn't seem like it since it happens in all cases for a majority of TXs. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any recommendations for solution?